# Meaning of ItemGroup added by Visual Studio in .NET MAUI app

Tags: maui

Visual Studio automatically added this section in the project file of my .NET MAUI app.

Any idea why? What does this section mean/do? Can I remove it?

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="Platforms\Android\google-services.json" />
  <None Remove="Platforms\Android\Resources\xml\network_security_config.xml" />
  <None Remove="Resources\Images\arrow_left_graphite.png" />
  <None Remove="Resources\Images\generic_image.png" />
  <None Remove="Resources\Raw\notification.mp3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Strange thing is that this list is not even a complete one. There are other images in the `Resources\Images` folder. There are also other items in the  `Resources\Raw` folder. Not sure why Visual Studio arbitrarily picked these items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these items are being automatically generated in the appropriate Resource group when certain files or items are added to your project. And they have no effect and can be safely removed or commented out from the `CSPROJ` file.

Since these files are in the `<None>` group which means they don't matter. If you have any other concerns, you can report via Visual Studio tooling issues: Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see [How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-201).